# manipulating the cells during the merge of two excel files

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I m trying to add a title between two excel files when i merge them.These two files has tables, and I m able to merge them together but i couldnt figure out how to add a title between these two tables.
the part of my code which is responsible for merging sheets looks like this;

```
public static void addSheet(org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet mergedSheet, org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet sheet,String title) {
        // map for cell styles
        Map<Integer, org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle> styleMap = new HashMap<Integer, org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle>();

        // This parameter is for appending sheet rows to mergedSheet in the end
        int len = mergedSheet.getLastRowNum();
        for (int j = sheet.getFirstRowNum(); j <= sheet.getLastRowNum(); j++) {

            org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row row = sheet.getRow(j);
            org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row mrow = mergedSheet.createRow(len + j + 1);
            try {
                for (int k = row.getFirstCellNum(); k < row.getLastCellNum(); k++) {
                org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell cell=null;
                if(row.getCell(k)!=null){
                 cell = row.getCell(k);
                }else{
                    cell= row.createCell(k);
                }
                org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell mcell = mrow.createCell(k);

                if (cell.getSheet().getWorkbook() == mcell.getSheet()
                        .getWorkbook()) {
                    mcell.setCellStyle(cell.getCellStyle());
                } else {
                    int stHashCode = cell.getCellStyle().hashCode();
                    org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle newCellStyle = styleMap.get(stHashCode);
                    if (newCellStyle == null) {
                        newCellStyle = mcell.getSheet().getWorkbook()
                                .createCellStyle();
                        newCellStyle.cloneStyleFrom(cell.getCellStyle());
                        styleMap.put(stHashCode, newCellStyle);
                    }
                    mcell.setCellStyle(newCellStyle);
                }

                switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA:
                    mcell.setCellFormula(cell.getCellFormula());
                    break;
                case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                    mcell.setCellValue(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                    break;
                case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                    mcell.setCellValue(cell.getStringCellValue());
                    break;
                case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
                    mcell.setCellType(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK);
                    break;
                case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                    mcell.setCellValue(cell.getBooleanCellValue());
                    break;
                case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_ERROR:
                    mcell.setCellErrorValue(cell.getErrorCellValue());
                    break;
                default:
                    mcell.setCellValue(cell.getStringCellValue());
                    break;
                }
            }
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }

        }
    }
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

Might not be what you want, but you COULD create a third excel file with ONLY the title.

Comment: Ahh, I see.  You could also create the spreadsheet within your code and pass it the title you wish....or add it to the first/last row of the preceding/next spreadsheet before merge without saving.

Comment: do you have any example ? it would be great

Comment: Not incredibly experienced with Java:
   
addCaption(mergedsheet, 0, LastY + 1, title);

But possibly something like this?